# Integration of the TestRail in Appium for Mobile automation

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

```
reporters:
        [
            ['testrail', {
                projectId: ,
                suiteId: 1,
                domain: '*****.testrail.io',
                username: 'User Name',
                apiToken: 'Generated Api token from the My Settings',
                runName: 'Testing',
                oneReport: true,
                includeAll: false
              
            }
        ]
    ]
```

I am trying to use the TestRail Reporter, But it is keep throwing the error  "TestrailReporter: Failed to update test run results: Request failed with status code 403"